# xml linq cannot remove the element

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i have a problem with my xml.

i need to remove all the the tags that are not in my list

but its not working in the `dd` tag

here is the xml input

http://pastebin.com/J8KkkMDJ

here is my list. this list are the tags that are only allowed in the xml

```
            lstApprove.Add("Styles");
            lstApprove.Add("alto");
            lstApprove.Add("Description");
            lstApprove.Add("MeasurementUnit");
            lstApprove.Add("sourceImageInformation");
            lstApprove.Add("fileName");
            lstApprove.Add("OCRProcessing");
            lstApprove.Add("preProcessingStep");
            lstApprove.Add("processingSoftware");
            lstApprove.Add("softwareCreator");
            lstApprove.Add("softwareName");
            lstApprove.Add("softwareVersion");
            lstApprove.Add("ocrProcessingStep");
            lstApprove.Add("ParagraphStyle");
            lstApprove.Add("Layout");
            lstApprove.Add("Page");
            lstApprove.Add("PrintSpace");
            lstApprove.Add("TextBlock");
            lstApprove.Add("TextLine");
            lstApprove.Add("String");
            lstApprove.Add("SP");
            lstApprove.Add("ComposedBlock");
            lstApprove.Add("GraphicalElement");
```

and here is the code for removing the tags that are not on the list

```
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(xmlFile))
                {

                    nAlto = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    nAlto = nAlto.Replace("<document xmlns=\"http://www.scansoft.com/omnipage/xml/ssdoc-schema3.xsd\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">", "<document>");
                    nAlto = nAlto.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>", "");
                }


                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(nAlto);
                    foreach (var item in doc.Descendants().ToList())
                    {
                        if (!lstApprove.Contains(item.Name.ToString()))
                        {
                            if (item.HasElements)
                            {
                                item.ReplaceWith(item.Elements());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                item.Remove();
                            }
                        }

                    }
```

and here is the output

http://pastebin.com/XjYBTWci

this is the part of xml output

```
<dd l="2342.29" t="133.12" r="2427.71" b="209.17">
          <TextBlock ID="P1_TB0000001" TAGREFS="LAYOUT_TAG_001" HPOS="2349.17" VPOS="160" WIDTH="71.66" HEIGHT="36.04" STYLEREFS="PAR_LEFT">
            <TextLine ID="P1_TL0000001" HPOS="2362.92" VPOS="160" WIDTH="44.16" HEIGHT="36.04">
              <String ID="P1_ST0000001" HPOS="2362.92" VPOS="160" WIDTH="44.16" HEIGHT="36.04" CONTENT="43" />
            </TextLine>
          </TextBlock>
        </dd>
```

i still have the `dd` tag, even if its not in my list. why? thank you

Comment: it's because you are looking only at the first-level descendants. What you need is recursion.

Comment: can you teach me how to do it recursive?

Comment: @HristoYankov [`Descendants()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635(v=vs.110).aspx) returns all descendant elements, not just the first level (unlike [`Elements()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you replace the item with its elements the Item is removed from the xDocument and so are its children so when you try to remove any of the children of the removed element, in your case the `<dd>` element it is detached from your xDocument so it hasn't any effect on it. To overcome this problem you need to store the parent of the Element you are removing and then iterate recursively over its children

```
    public static void RemoveRecursive(XElement current, List<string> goodNames)
    {
        var parent = current;
        if (!goodNames.Contains(current.Name.ToString()))
        {
            parent = current.Parent;

            current.ReplaceWith(current.Elements());
        }
        foreach (var element in parent.Elements())
        {
            RemoveRecursive(element, goodNames);
        }

    }
```

try this function where `current` is `doc.Root` and `goodNames` is `lstApprove`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with your code is you are missing the closing forward slash on "/document" in the replace.  The code below works

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> lstApprove = new List<string>() {
                "Styles", "alto", "Description", "MeasurementUnit",
                "sourceImageInformation",
                "fileName", "OCRProcessing", "preProcessingStep",
                "processingSoftware", "softwareCreator", "softwareName",
                "softwareVersion", "ocrProcessingStep", "ParagraphStyle",
                "Layout", "Page", "PrintSpace", "TextBlock",
                "TextLine", "String", "SP", "ComposedBlock", "GraphicalElement"
            };


            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> elements = doc.Descendants().Where(x => lstApprove.Contains(x.Name.LocalName)).ToList();

            string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>" +
                         "<document xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"></document>";

            XDocument newDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement document = (XElement)newDoc.FirstNode;
            document.Add(elements);
        }
    }
}
```